# How can I raise a QML widget to the top?

Tags: qt, qml

Let's say I have two overlapping QML Widgets, two Buttons for example. In normal Qt, there is `QWidget.raise_()` and `QWidget::raise()` to do this. Is there something similar in QML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show an Item over another then it is enough that the property [`z`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) is greater than the other.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1

        width: 0.7 * parent.width
        height: 0.6 * parent.height
        color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2

        width: 0.7 * parent.width
        height: 0.6 * parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        color: "blue"
        z: 1
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 500
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (rect1.z == 0) {
                rect1.z = 1;
                rect2.z = 0;
            } else {
                rect1.z = 0;
                rect2.z = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it should be noticed that `z` works for sibling items only.

Comment: @folibis I assume the OP knows this since raise() also works for QWidget siblings

Comment: you're right but anyway, in my experience, this is the most common mistake with `z`, so I always try to focus on this.

Comment: They're all siblings.

Comment: It's model data, so there's no direct references and I can't determine how many there are.